# Convert all key names of an object to strings

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an object like:

```
obj = {"a": 1, "b": 2, c: 3}
```

this object is returned by a Node.js package.

I want to pass this object to a `request` headers but it fails because `c` in that object has invalid key name I guess.

Is it possible to convert all the key names of my object to strings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `JSON.stringify()` to convert it to a valid JSON string:

```js
obj = JSON.stringify({"a": 1, "b": 2, c: 3});
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: This is a string tho, should I do `JSON.parse()` to convert it back into an object?

Comment: @MatrixCow08 When you want to de-serialize the JSON string back to an object you can use the `JSON.parse()`,

Comment: `JSON.parse()` seems to bring back `c` as how it was

Comment: @MatrixCow08 Yes that is converting the JSON string back into a *JavaScript Object*, that is why you won't see quotes around any of the keys in the returned value from the `JSON.parse()` call. JS objects don't need a double quote around them unless they have a white space in between but the JSON standard does.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new object and call `toString()` while creating the key

```
const obj = {
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  c: 3
};
const newObj = {};
for (let keys in obj) {
  newObj[keys.toString()]: obj[keys]
}
```

Comment: This isn't pushing anything to `newObj` I guess

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, all object keys that are not symbols are converted to strings.

```
obj = {1: 1}
obj['1'] = 2;
// obj is {1: 2}
```

If you got such an 'object' from node package it means the data has not been prepared correctly - probably somebody has created JSON by hand (writing a string instead of stringify an object).

If you want to add " to all keys and change an object to a string, so, in other words, make a JSON out of it - you can use `JSON.stringify(obj) //"{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}"`

If you want to make an object out of such a broken JSON:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)) // "{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}"
```